# Flutter Remove Duplicated ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

In my application, i'm  getting an API response as follows

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "items": [
            {
                "sequenceno": 1933,
                "_id": "5eff1",
                "chapter": "Numbers and Numeration",
                "title": "Place Value: 3-digits",
                "package_description": "This learning module helps to familiarise with the concept of place value of 3-digit numbers.",
                "age_level": [
                    99,
                    8
                ],
                "pkg_sequence": "2501",
                "packagescors": {
                    "score": [
                        50
                    ],
                    "date": [
                        "1600259121340"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "sequenceno": 1933,
                "_id": "5d79",
                "chapter": "Numbers and Numeration",
                "title": "Place Value: 4-digits",
                "package_description": "This learning module helps the kids familiarise with the concept of Place value of a number.",
                "age_level": [
                    99,
                    8
                ],
                "pkg_sequence": "2501",
                "packagescors": {
                    "score": [
                        60
                    ],
                    "date": [
                        "1615283866457"
                    ]
                }
            },
            ]
```

The data is modules from a subject with chapters and titles under chapters. Each data has a key named 'chapter'. Whenever the listview is built the data gets duplicated

[image: ListView Flutter]

How can I remove duplicates and properly build the list?

Answer (score 0):

**Try out this.**

```html
final ids = myList.map((e) => e.id).toSet();
    myList.retainWhere((x) => ids.remove(x.id)); // set your response param instead of id.
```